# Configuring Parameters for Web Package Deployment to modify config element

Tags: xml, parameters, build, config, msdeploy

I have this web.config and I wish to alter a xml element at build using msdeploy tool.

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="customBinaryBinding">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="20971520"/>
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" authenticationScheme="Negotiate" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

How to I have to configure my Parameters.xml and SetParameters in order to make it change from `httpTransport` to `httpsTransport`. I'm new at this, please bear with me :).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace an XML node with a parameterEntry match value that targets the node you wish to replace as an XPath reference.  For example,

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="MyTestParam" description="My Test Param" defaultValue="&lt;httpsTransport  /&gt;">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="web\.config" match="//binding[@name='customBinaryBinding']/httpTransport" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

The following blog post has more details -

https://blogs.iis.net/elliotth/web-deploy-xml-file-parameterization

Also one quick correction, WebDeploy Parameterization occurs at deploy time not build time.  This is preferred so you can build once, create a package and deploy it many times to different environments.  The following post describes parameterization and introduces a helpful VS extensions for previewing parameterization results.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/